# Csrftoken is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm using the following code as recommended by the documentation:

```
            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
                // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
                return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }
```

```
            $("#formTabla").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                        }
                    }
                    url : "{% url 'submit' %}",
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: {
                        "checkboxes": formData,
                        "datos": todosDatos
                    },
                    success: function (respuesta){
                    }
                });
            });
```

I'm getting the error :

```
 "Uncaught ReferenceError: csrftoken is not defined".
```

I understand why this happens, but I have no idea how to solve it. How and where am I supposed to define crsftoken?

Comment: Have you checked if the header is being set? If it's not being set then you simply need to determine why the logic flow isn't hitting your `if` condition. If it is being set, what is the value of `csrftoken`?

Comment: `csrftoken` has no value, it's not defined anywhere. Hence my original question: How and where am I supposed to define crsftoken?

Comment: Googling 'how to generate a CSRF token django' got me this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajaxSend() for this

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable is not defined anywhere, first you need to obtain csrf_token:

```
import Cookies from 'cookies-js'
let csrftoken  = Cookies.get('csrftoken')
```

then set the variable in request header.